# Is there PATH environment variable for python scripts within python?

Tags: python, windows

In PowerShell (or CMD), i can run `PS>myscript.py` from anywhere, because i added it's path to the PATH environment variable.
Problem is, it will open a new window, that closes after execution. So i can't see the script output afterwards.

If i run `PS>python myscript.py`, i get output in the current shell, as desired.
But i have to be in the script's path or supply it in the command.

Is there a way to make python lookup scripts in the PATH env?

Or is there a kind of PATH env. for python?

Or even better, is there a way to get the python output in current shell, even if i call just `PS>myscript.py`?

Comment: `python -m myscript`

Comment: @AhmedAEK i think he would need PYTHONPATH for that instead of PATH though :P but yes (with a few other caveats)